# how to update excel file data using php

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, phpexcel, codeigniter-3

i have to update a excel file with multiple sheet and every sheet contain some formula related to each sheet i found a PHP excel code for creating new excel file from old excel file data but i need a code  that will update a excel file value of a particular sheet .

```
    $this->load->library('excel');
    $excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $excel2 = $excel2->load('excel2.xlsx'); // Empty Sheet
    $excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C6', '4')
        ->setCellValue('C7', '5')
        ->setCellValue('C8', '6')
        ->setCellValue('C9', '7');

    $excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
    $excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A7', '4')
        ->setCellValue('C7', '5');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('excel3.xlsx');
```

`

Comment: Set the active sheet to whichever sheet you want to change the cells in, then change them

Comment: i just have to update only one sheet but when the time comes to update any excel sheet i have to copy whole excel sheet  data and than recreate it  again.and its not possible to copy only one sheet data because every sheet is depend on each other through formulas.

Comment: I can't understand what the problem is.... why do you need to copy the sheet? When you load the workbook, you're loading all the sheets in the workbook

Comment: ok let me explain , i have a sheet which have around 8 sheet each sheet have so many calculative formulas which depend on other sheets .my main task is to change the first dependent values in formulas of sheet and show all data of the sheet which calculated after the new value are changed

Comment: chk this https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-edit-excel-sheets-php/